# How can I remove wrong/old entries in the 'send to' in Google Map

Tags: google-maps

When I want to send a google map location to my phone, this dialog shows up

[image]

there are many phone entries in the dialog but only one of them is valid.

However I can't find where to remove the old records.

How can I remove these phones entries from the dialog?

Answer (score -1):

> How can I remove wrong/old entries in the 'send to' in Google Maps?

See: "[Google Maps Help - Send directions to your phone, car, or tablet](https://support.google.com/maps/answer/6081481?hl=en)":

> ...
>
> **Step 2: Send a place**
>
> 1. On a computer, open Google Maps. If you're using Maps in a mobile browser or an older web browser or operating system, this might not work.
> 2. Find the place you want to send.
> 3. Below the search box, click Send to your phone. Then, choose an option:
>
>    - Choose the phone or tablet you want to send to.
>    - Click Send to car and then Send.
>    - If you don't have a device or car listed, you can send by email or text message. Text isn't available in all countries. [Learn how to add or change your phone number stored in your Google Account](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/183723).
>
> ...

Clicking that link takes you to "Set up a recovery phone number or email address":

> **Add or change a recovery phone number**
>
> 1. On your Android phone or tablet, open your device's Settings app ⚙️ and then Google and then Google Account.
> 2. At the top, tap Security.
> 3. Under "Ways we can verify it's you," tap Recovery phone. You might need to sign in.
> 4. From here, you can:
>
>    - Add a recovery phone.
>    - Change your recovery phone: Next to your number, select Edit Edit.
>    - **Delete your recovery phone**: Next to your number, select Delete Delete.
>
>      > Delete the numbers (locations) that you do not want.
> 5. Follow the steps on the screen.
>
> Note: Deleting your recovery phone number doesn’t delete it from being used for other Google services. Go to your account to [manage your phone numbers](https://myaccount.google.com/phone).

Clicking that last link shows ***all*** the registered phone numbers and this text:

> **Have Google verify your number**
>     Google can auto-verify phone numbers on some devices. This helps keep your account up to date. [Learn more](https://support.google.com/android/bin/answer/7521240?hl=en)
>
> > ℹ️ You may have added phone numbers that aren’t listed here. If a number you added to a Google service isn’t listed here, go to that service to control how it’s used.

If you used someone else's phone, changed your phone number, or have incorrect information, use those links to verify your ***current*** phone and delete all the unused access points.